# JavaScript to read a string on the webpage

Tags: javascript, string, search, greasemonkey

I'm trying to use Greasemonkey to create a JS that can read a particular string in a webpage and if found it should display an alert box. This webpage is an internal site used in my office.

I used a simple code and it only reads the words which is present in the source HTML code and not the ones in the webpage

Comment: 1) What is your problem? 2) Where is your erros? 3) Where is your code? 4) Why are you agreed with rules without read it?!

Comment: Just wrap your UserScript in a `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){` …code here… `})`. Then put the code that checks the page directly (e. g. `if(document.body.innerHTML.match(/` … `/)!=null){` … `}`) inside the function body.

Comment: I used the following code : `if (/blocking/i.test (document.body.innerHTML) )
{
    alert ("Found blocking !");
}`..How do I combine with the code you suggested ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Z2d3ZA1C